# Problema al restar fechas en excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Tengo un problema al querer hacer una diferencia entre dos fechas para saber los días entre ellas.
Estas por un lado

```
3/15/17 17:58
3/15/17 17:57
3/15/17 17:55
```

y por otro

```
2017-03-29 00:05:49 UTC
2017-06-15 00:40:49 UTC
2017-03-15 01:12:21 UTC
```

en la segunda me estorba el UTC como podría quitarlo? y si es necesario como quitar la hora para poder usar la función dias(fecha1,fecha2) si no afecta en la función puedo dejarlo.
También desearia cambiar el formato para que tengan el mismo, ya intente cambiarlo seleccionando la columna y usando ctrl+1 pero solo cambia algunas y otras las deja igual.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema (y el más complicado) es la primer fecha que se encuentra en formato `m/d/yy`, para convertirla en una fecha real, hay que extraer las partes y al año le sumamos 2000 para poder convertirla adecuadamente. La formula sería:

```
=FECHA(EXTRAE(A5;ENCONTRAR(" ";A5)-2;2)+2000;EXTRAE(A5;1;ENCONTRAR("/";A5)-1);EXTRAE(A5;ENCONTRAR("/";A5)+1;ENCONTRAR("/";A5;ENCONTRAR("/";A5)+1)-ENCONTRAR("/";A5)-1))
```

La celda de ejemplo es `A5`. No podemos hacer un recorte por posiciones fijas por que el formato es variable, tanto el día como el mes pueden tener 1 o 2 caracteres, por lo que tenemos que detectar los caracteres de separación y hacer una aritmética medio complicada con ellos. Seguramente con VBA podríamos usar expresiones regulares, que es un poco más simple.

La otra fecha es más fácil de convertir, ya que el formato es fijo `yyyy-mm-dd`, con lo cual la extración de datos es más directa. La formula:

```
=FECHA(EXTRAE(C6;1;4);EXTRAE(C6;6;2);EXTRAE(C6;9;2))
```

La celda base del ejemplo es `C6`

Comment: Solo una corrección el formato de la primera parte es de Estados Unidos (mes/día/año) saludos.

Comment: Es ciero @virtualdvid, gracias por la corrección, la formula lo contemplaba pero la explicación no.